# Laravel Legacy URL Routing

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble getting the below to work. I want to route legacy urls but the below does not seem to work. When I access `products.php?pid=x&flag=x` I get a not found error. I expect to see the new Product ID. What I am missing?

```
Route::get('/products.php?pid={products_id}&flag={flag}', function($products_id = null, $flag = null) {

    if ($pid) {
        echo 'New Product ID: ' . $pid;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel does not route through the query string. Use this instead:

```php
Route::get('products.php', function()
{
    $pid = Input::get('pid');

    $flag = Input::get('flag');

    if ($pid)
    {
        echo 'New Product ID: ' . $pid;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this going to products.php?pid=1234&flag=2 and it shows nothing. I would expect New PRoduct ID but I get nothing. Any suggestions? I'm using Laravel 4.2 if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

In your route function, you are trying to access $pid, which is not defined as a parameter. What you can access is $products_id.

If you modify route url in this way `'/products.php?pid={pid}&flag={flag}'` and modify function paramter in this way `function($pid = null, $flag = null)`, it should work fine.